# Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when i tried to create a scaffold inside the rails application it shows me the error like this. so how can i generate scaffold for now.

this is what i've done.

```
llocalhost@localhost:~/rain/log$ rails new scaffold user login_name:string password:string

Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.

This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub rails` to work around a system/bundle conflict.

Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.

Type 'rails' for help.
```

Comment: is `log` your rails app directory, if yes, you need to use `rails g scaffold user login_name:string password:string` otherwise you need to run the above command out of that directory(another rails app directory) as specified in error

Comment: Can I add it as answer then

Answer (score 0):

You're in a subdirectory of your Rails application.

To resolve the problem, change to the top level directory of your application, and then try again.