# Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

When I run a rails console using

```
rails console
```

everything is fine.

When I run a rails console using

```
bundle exec rails console
```

I get the following warning

```
Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub my_gem` to work around a system/bundle conflict.
```

`my_gem` happens to be a gem that I've created that is completely unrelated and not used in the current project directory.

I've tried every solution in this question with no luck:
[Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211173/bundler-is-using-a-binstub-that-was-created-for-a-different-gem)

I would appreciate any guidance on removing this warning or help understanding how binstubs work so that I can figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays it's common for projects to have "specialized" versions of tools. E.g. in some projects the "rails" command may be expected to be run using "spring" (to start up faster).

So it's not uncommon to generate files in your project's 'bin' directory, and then use those versions when running commands, so e.g. instead of

```
bundle exec rails console
```

or

```
bundle exec spring rails console
```

you could simply expect the following to work correctly

```
bin/rails console
```

and not care whether the project needs spring or bundler or zeus or whatever.

So if you don't have 'bin/rails' in your project, you should generate one that suits the project, e.g. using

```
bin/rake rails:update:bin
```

If you don't already have bin/rake, you might have to use

```
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

(so your bin/rake commands will also get a speedup from using spring)

Some people even put `./bin` in their paths, so whenever they run `rake` (or whatever) they are actually running `./bin/rake` if it exists.

#### Troubleshooting

1. for project specific tasks, use `bin/*` files, creating them if needed (e.g. using special rake tasks like in Rails or using `bundle binstub <gemname>`) - usually those have Bundler specific lines that will make Bundler happy.
2. for non-project gems (like your gem), find out where it is (e.g. `which mygem`) and check out it's contents - it's probably using e.g. "bundler/setup" which is confusing Bundler (because bundler expects a local Gemfile file). Maybe your gem is using bundler (it shouldn't if it's a "global" kind of tool and not a "project" tool).
3. Also, if you're using them, check if tools like RVM and .rbenv are correctly adding *their* stuff to your bin files (they usually need to setup specific paths)
4. If you still have questions, it's best to post the contents of the bin file causing problems - it's meant to be a plain Ruby file, so if there's something wrong, it's usually because of the file contents (and not anything else).

More info: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs

Comment: great great answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It happened in a project of mine. Because I ran `bundle install` with another ruby version.

Make sure your `rvm` is the correctly ruby version.